# How to stop part from rotating with BodyGyro?

Tags: roblox

I am trying to make a part move in a certain direction without it being able to be pushed or rotated by the player's body. I am using bodygyro to stop the part from being rotated. The orientation of the part is `0, 90, 0`. This is what the bodygyro properties are:

[image]

The problem is the bodygyro is rotating the part back to `0,0,0` orientation. How can I stop it from rotating the part back to `0,0,0` but also stop the part from being rotated by the player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a bodyVelocity inside of the part to stop it from rotating. Make sure the angularVelocity is set to `0, 0, 0`